# Check for parameters value in ant build.xml

Tags: ant, conditional-statements, build.xml

I have a requirement where in a build.xml file I have two variables.

While calling the build.xml file from Java program, I will pass the values as properties
And while calling the same build.xml file from command line, it should ask the user for input

Now I have to check whether a particular property is having any value or not, if not, then ask user to input the value

Can you please help me to write this build.xml file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<target name="printMyProperty" depends="askUser">
    <echo message="${my.property}"/>
</target>

<target name="askUser" unless="my.property">
    <input
            message="Enter the value for my.property:"
            addproperty="my.property"
            />
</target>
```

The `unless` attribute is the solution to your problem. It means "execute this target only if my.property is not set".